# How do I implement directive (ng-template) in Angular?

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, ng-template

In my HTML file, I've duplicated the "elseBlock2". How do I implement directive (ng-template) to handle it?

```
<div class="col-2">
   <ng-container *ngIf="item.isSuccess; else elseBlock2">
      {{getSimplifiedSize(item.file.size)}}
   </ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="item.progress; else elseBlock2">
      {{item.progress}}%
      <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" color="primary" value={{item.progress}}></mat-progress-bar>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain little more what you actually wants to do?

Comment: This code is for the Upload Files function. When `item.isSuccess` where the file is uploaded, I want the file size to be displayed at the progress bar together with 100%. And when `item.progress` where the file is uploading, I want the 100% to be displayed at the progress bar. Sorry my explanation is a bit confusing.

Comment: This is the reason I hate Angular, you can't even do simple `else-if`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can work something like this?

```
<div class="col-2">
  <ng-container *ngIf="(item.isSuccess || item.progress); else elseBlock2">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.isSuccess">
      {{getSimplifiedSize(item.file.size)}}
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.progress">
      {{item.progress}}%
      <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" color="primary" value={{item.progress}}></mat-progress-bar>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #elseBlock2>
    Your content
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

**Update:**

If you want to display the *elseBlock* only when it's both not in *progress* and *success* you can do something like this:

```
<div class="col-2">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.isSuccess">
        {{getSimplifiedSize(item.file.size)}}
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.progress">
        {{item.progress}}%
        <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" color="primary" value={{item.progress}}></mat-progress-bar>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="!item.progress && !item.isSuccess">
        Your content
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: So my work is for Upload Files function. Your method works but "Your content" is displaying shortly at the start of uploading process and also once the upload process is completed. How to make it displays only after the upload process completed?

Comment: Try in this way:  `<ng-container *ngIf="item.isSuccess">...</ng-container><ng-container *ngIf="item.progress">...</ng-container><ng-container *ngIf="!item.progress && !item.isSuccess">...</ng-container>` removing the ng-container we added previously.

Answer (score 1):

You can use if then else with ternary operator to achieve `else-if` in Angular

```html
<ng-container
  *ngIf="item.isSuccess then successBlock; else (item.progress) ? progressBlock : elseBlock"
></ng-container>

<ng-template #successBlock>
  {{ getSimplifiedSize(item.file.size) }}
</ng-template>

<ng-template #progressBlock>
  {{ item.progress }}%
</ng-template>

<ng-template #elseBlock>
  Error
</ng-template>
```

In else statement, instead of passing a template, do another conditional check with ternary operator and pass other two templates as values